# Flink akka AskTimeoutException on AWS EMR when the input file size is large

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr, rml-rdf

I execute [RMLStreamer](https://github.com/RMLio/RMLStreamer) on AWS EMR, when my file size (csv file) is small (30-50 rows) everything works fine and I receive the expected outcome. However, as I increase my file size from 30 rows to few thousand rows. I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$2(MiniClusterJobClient.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1061)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:264)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef.$bang(AskSupport.scala:572)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:22)
    at akka.pattern.PipeToSupport$PipeableFuture$$anonfun$pipeTo$1.applyOrElse(PipeToSupport.scala:21)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:436)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Future.scala:435)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:90)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:224)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.notifyTaskFailure(UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.notifySchedulerNgAboutInternalTaskFailure(ExecutionGraph.java:1869)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1462)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1402)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.markFailed(Execution.java:1230)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.lambda$deploy$11(Execution.java:879)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:456)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRunAsync(AkkaRpcActor.java:440)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Invocation of public abstract java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorGateway.submitTask(org.apache.flink.runtime.deployment.TaskDeploymentDescriptor,org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMasterId,org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time) timed out.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(CompletableFuture.java:925)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:913)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaInvocationHandler.lambda$invokeRpc$0(AkkaInvocationHandler.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$1.onComplete(FutureUtils.java:1059)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:263)
    at akka.dispatch.OnComplete.internal(Future.scala:261)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:191)
    at akka.dispatch.japi$CallbackBridge.apply(Future.scala:188)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.Executors$DirectExecutionContext.execute(Executors.java:73)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:44)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:252)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:644)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Invocation of public abstract java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutorGateway.submitTask(org.apache.flink.runtime.deployment.TaskDeploymentDescriptor,org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMasterId,org.apache.flink.api.common.time.Time) timed out.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.RpcTaskManagerGateway.submitTask(RpcTaskManagerGateway.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.lambda$deploy$10(Execution.java:855)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://flink/user/rpc/taskmanager_0#-1412776320]] after [10000 ms]. Message of type [org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.messages.LocalRpcInvocation]. A typical reason for `AskTimeoutException` is that the recipient actor didn't send a reply.
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$2.apply(AskSupport.scala:635)
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:648)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:205)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:328)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:279)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:283)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:235)
    ... 1 more
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

I tried to change the following Flink configuration (individually and in combination of other properties) to resolve the problem but I always get the exact same error.

```
akka.ask.timeout: 10min
akka.client.timeout: 10min
web.timeout: 1000000
taskmanager.heap.size:9096m
taskmanager.memory.size:7096m
jobmanager.heap.size:5048m
taskmanager.memory.fraction: 0.9
```

```
EMR Version:emr-5.33.0
Master: 1 m5.xlarge 
Core:2 m5.xlarge
```

Comment: How did You try to change them? Were the changes applied correctly ? I.e. if you set `akka.ask.timeout: 10min` does it take 10mins before it fails ?